# $\|Ax - R(A,x)x\|_2 = \inf_{\alpha \in \mathbb R}\|Ax - \alpha x\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the proof of $$\|Ax - R(A,x)x\|_2 = \inf_{\alpha \in \mathbb R}\|Ax - \alpha x\|_2,$$
where $R(A,x) = \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$ is the Rayleigh quotient of $A$. How to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
\begin{align*}
\inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} \|Ax - \alpha x\|_2 ={}& \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} \|Ax - \alpha x\|_2^2 \\
={}& \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} x^\top (A-\alpha I)^\top(A - \alpha I)x \\
={}& \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} x^\top (A^\top A - \alpha A^\top - \alpha A + \alpha^2 I)x \\
={}& \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} (\|x\|_2^2\alpha^2 - 2x^\top Ax \alpha + \|Ax\|_2^2).
\end{align*}
This is a convex quadratic in $\alpha$. Setting the derivative to zero gives $2\|x\|_2^2 \alpha^* - 2 x^\top A x = 0$, so
\begin{equation*}
\alpha^* = \frac{x^\top A x}{x^\top x} = R(A,x).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Do we have to assume that $A$ is symmetric here?

Comment: No, I believe the the only assumption on $A$ that we used above is that it's square. Are you concerned with how we combine the $\alpha A^\top$ term and the $\alpha A$ term? If so, recall that $x^\top Ax$ is a scalar, and therefore $x^\top A x = (x^\top Ax)^\top = x^\top A^\top x$.